Getting "ERROR: unrecognized node type: 444" while creating an AST
I'm running version 16. I'm working with a table structure as follows:
Table: MyTable
Columns: 
- ColumnA (JSONB)
- ColumnB (TEXT)
- ColumnC (INT8)
- ColumnD (INT8)

The primary key is a composite of ColumnB + ColumnC.
I’m trying to create an AST representation of a query for the INSERT operation. The initial AST for a simple insert looks like this:
INSERT INTO <myTable> (ColumnA, ColumnB)
VALUES (<list of values>)

This structure works well for inserting data. However, I recently added another column (ColumnD), and the updated insert query is as follows:
INSERT INTO <myTable> (ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD)
VALUES (<list of values>)
ON CONFLICT (ColumnB, ColumnC)
DO UPDATE SET
    ColumnA = EXCLUDED.ColumnA,
    ColumnD = EXCLUDED.ColumnD
WHERE ColumnD < <timestampEpochInSeconds>
RETURNING ColumnA;

I’m trying to add the ON CONFLICT expression to the AST, but I’m encountering an "Unrecognized Node" error.
What I've tried

I’ve tried various ways to construct the struct, but the error persists.
Found this thread discussing the issue and followed the steps setting up verbose error logging and using gdb to print full backtrace.
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CADTdw-yGfNyHSLXajBFgCEod9dCh8Ys2%3D9j-gNh6kX5oEpkRNA%40mail.gmail.com
I found through logs that the error originates from line 2053 in NodeFuncs.c. I can’t correlate the unrecognized node to any enum value in Nodes.h. Any pointers on how to navigate that file would be greatly appreciated! The logs after setting error logging to verbose-

2024-10-01 06:38:34.040 UTC [96871] ERROR:  XX000: unrecognized node type: 444
2024-10-01 06:38:34.040 UTC [96871] LOCATION:  expression_tree_walker_impl, nodeFuncs.c:2539

The bt logs were not very useful since all variables were 'optimized out'.
Here's the code I used to construct the query:
Query *createInsertQuery() {
    Query *query = makeNode(Query);
    query->commandType = CMD_INSERT;
    query->querySource = QSRC_ORIGINAL;
    query->canSetTag = true;

    /* Base table RTE */
    RangeTblEntry *rte = makeNode(RangeTblEntry);
    List *colNames = list_make4(makeString("colA"), makeString("colB"),
                                 makeString("colC"), makeString("colD"));

    rte->rtekind = RTE_RELATION;
    rte->relid = myTable->relationId;
    rte->alias = rte->eref = makeAlias("myTable", colNames);
    rte->lateral = false;
    rte->inFromCl = false;
    rte->relkind = RELKIND_RELATION;
    rte->functions = NIL;
    rte->inh = true;

    RTEPermissionInfo *permInfo = addRTEPermissionInfo(&query->rteperminfos, rte);
    permInfo->requiredPerms = ACL_INSERT;

    rte->rellockmode = RowExclusiveLock;
    query->rtable = lappend(query->rtable, rte);
    query->resultRelation = 1;

    /* VALUES RTE */
    List *valuesColNames = list_make4(makeString("colA"), makeString("colB"),
                                       makeString("colC"), makeString("colD"));
    RangeTblEntry *valuesRte = makeNode(RangeTblEntry);
    valuesRte->rtekind = RTE_VALUES;
    valuesRte->alias = valuesRte->eref = makeAlias("values", valuesColNames);
    valuesRte->lateral = false;
    valuesRte->inFromCl = false;
    valuesRte->values_lists = list_make1(values);
    valuesRte->inh = false;
    valuesRte->inFromCl = true;

    valuesRte->coltypes = list_make4_oid(JSONBOID, TEXTOID, INT8OID, INT8OID);
    valuesRte->coltypmods = list_make4_int(-1, -1, -1, -1);
    valuesRte->colcollations = list_make4_oid(InvalidOid, InvalidOid, InvalidOid, InvalidOid);
    query->rtable = lappend(query->rtable, valuesRte);

    RangeTblRef *valuesRteRef = makeNode(RangeTblRef);
    valuesRteRef->rtindex = 2;
    List *fromList = list_make1(valuesRteRef);
    query->jointree = makeFromExpr(fromList, NULL);

    /* Target list */
    query->targetList = list_make4(
        makeTargetEntry((Expr *) makeVar(2, 1, JSONBOID, -1, InvalidOid, 0), 1, "colA", false),
        makeTargetEntry((Expr *) makeVar(2, 2, TEXTOID, -1, InvalidOid, 0), 2, "colB", false),
        makeTargetEntry((Expr *) makeVar(2, 3, INT8OID, -1, InvalidOid, 0), 3, "colC", false),
        makeTargetEntry((Expr *) makeVar(2, 4, INT8OID, -1, InvalidOid, 0), 4, "colD", false)
    );

    /* On Conflict */
    OnConflictExpr *onConflict = makeNode(OnConflictExpr);
    onConflict->action = ONCONFLICT_UPDATE;

    int64 myTimestamp = 1672531199; // Example timestamp

    ColumnRef *conflictColumnRef = makeNode(ColumnRef);
    conflictColumnRef->fields = list_make1(makeString("colD"));
    conflictColumnRef->location = -1;

    A_Expr *onConflictWhereExpr = makeSimpleA_Expr(AEXPR_OP, "<", (Node *)conflictColumnRef, 
        (Node *)makeConst(INT8OID, -1, InvalidOid, sizeof(int64), 
        Int64GetDatum((int)myTimestamp), false, true), -1);
    
    onConflict->onConflictWhere = (Node *)onConflictWhereExpr;

    /* Primary key */
    onConflict->arbiterElems = list_make2(makeString("colB"), makeString("colC"));

    TargetEntry *updateTargetD = makeTargetEntry((Expr *) makeVar(2, 4, INT8OID, -1, InvalidOid, 0),
                                                  4, "colD", false);
    TargetEntry *updateTargetA = makeTargetEntry((Expr *) makeVar(2, 1, JSONBOID, -1, InvalidOid, 0),
                                                  1, "colA", false);

    /* Update target list */
    onConflict->onConflictSet = list_make2(updateTargetA, updateTargetD);
    query->onConflict = onConflict;

    /* Returning list */
    query->returningList = list_make1(
        makeTargetEntry((Expr *) makeVar(1, 1, JSONBOID, -1, InvalidOid, 0),
                        1, "colA", false)
    );

    return query;
}



If you're bypassing SQL altogether and trying to query using internal structs this might be a bit specialist for stackoverflow. You will probably do better on the postgresql.org mailing lists.
